# Resetting unverified session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are two servers, `production.myapp.com` and `staging.myapp.com` that use cookie session store and that cookie is set for `myapp.com` domain. Is there a way to handle a session cookie that can't be decrypted/verified? Rails version is 5.1.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Documentaion for Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html). You can use an encrypted cookie and set the domain on the cookie to be `myapp.com`, i.e.

```
cookies.encrypted[:my-key] = {
  domain: ".myapp.com",
  secure: !Rails.env.development?,
  value: "put-your-value-here",
}
```

Note however, that both apps will need to share the `secret_key_base` since that is what is used to encrypt / read the cookie value.

If you want to delete it be sure to pass the domain as argument.

```
cookies.delete(:my-key, domain: ".my-app.com")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Apps use different `SECRET_KEY_BASE` and I want to `reset_session` when the app receives a cookie it can't deal with. The cookie is set for `myapp.com` domain intentionally for other services to work.

Comment: Well you could use a regular cookie and then just encrypt the value you put in it using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html#method-c-new and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html. But both apps will still need to share some sort of secret.

Comment: I don't want the session to be usable on both servers, I want to reset the session when a user logged in to staging goes to production.